# Ionic FCM notification tap on background not receiving data

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [Ionic FCM](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/) and [Laravel FCm package](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) to send notifications to the app.

The token gets stored in the Database, The notification is received in the app too. The problem is when the app is in background and notification is tapped the specific page isn't opening.

The code for handling notification tapped is taken from the Ionic docs:

```
console.log('This will print in all cases');
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
  console.log('this will will print when app in background', data);

  if (data.wasTapped) {
    console.log('This never gets printed', data);
    console.log("Received in background");
    this.nav.setRoot(CommunicationPage, { 'message_id': data.page_id });
  } else {
    console.log('Data: this will will print when app in background', data);
    this.nav.push(CommunicationPage, { 'message_id': data.page_id });
    console.log("Received in foreground");
  };
});
```

Comment: have you added the click action property in your notification payload.

Comment: use data instead of notification and refer this you will understand https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: @MaheshJadhav can you explain a little?

Comment: you must be sending a payload object right when you are sending notification

Comment: Yes! I am sending a page type and page id as payload. @MaheshJadhav

Comment: Not that have you used cloud functions to trigger the notification there you send the payload

Comment: Not sure If I am getting you but when I send it via the FCM panel I add these params in the custom data (sorry unable to attach screenshot in the comment)

Comment: Have you found a solution  ? I'm stuck in same issue

Comment: same issue.......

Comment: Same issue!! Any solution??

Comment: Hope you guys are using "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"